# Manipulating Python: datetime.now() output to display incrementing time values per individual line

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, output

Initially I was given an exercise in which I had to write the 'RandomFile.txt' as seven separate lines with each line listing the summation of integers given and the current time. After completing this task I was assigned to show an increment of one second per line (i.e first line = 5s, second line = 6s, third line = 7s, etc.) and to also increase the date beginning on the line pertaining to 'blank blank.'

Using the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

with open("C:\Users\curnutte\Desktop\Assignment\Python Scripts\Python example\RandomFile.txt", "r") as inp:
with open("C:\Users\curnutte\Desktop\Assignment\Python Scripts\Python example\RandomFileOutput.txt", "w") as outp:

    clock = datetime.now()


    for i, line in enumerate(inp.readlines()):
        total = 0
        line = line.strip()
        #print(line)
        parts = line.split(",")
        for part in parts:

            try:
                num = int(part)
                total += num

            except ValueError:
                total = (" ".join(parts))
                break


        #print(type(total))
        if type(total) == int:
            total_time = clock
            print (clock)
        else:
            total_time = clock + timedelta(days = 1)
            print (clock + timedelta(days = 1))

        outp.write("%s: " % total_time)
        outp.write("{}\n".format(total))
```

Here is 'RandomFile.txt:'

```
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,5
blank,blank
5,6
6,7
```

I get the output:

```
2016-06-29 09:21:15.168000: 3
2016-06-29 09:21:15.168000: 5
2016-06-29 09:21:15.168000: 7
2016-06-29 09:21:15.168000: 9
2016-06-30 09:21:15.168000: blank blank
2016-06-29 09:21:15.168000: 11
2016-06-29 09:21:15.168000: 13
```

However, I would like to achieve the following output:

```
2016-06-29 09:21:15.168000: 3
2016-06-29 09:21:**16**.168000: 5
2016-06-29 09:21:**17**.168000: 7
2016-06-29 09:21:**18**.168000: 9
2016-06-30 09:21:**19**.168000: blank blank
2016-06-**30** 09:21:**20**.168000: 11
2016-06-**30** 09:21:**21**.168000: 13
```

The changes I would like to see have been listed in bold text.

I feel like this is a relatively simple task, but as my username would lead you to believe, I am pretty new to Python (and even programming in general.) I thought that maybe using ticks would help, but really have no idea how to apply them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increment your time by one minute in some way inside this branch: `if type(total) == int:`. Currently, what you do is just assign `total_time` the original value of `clock` (which corresponds to your start time) instead of keeping track of the changing time value in some way.

Similarly, in that `else` branch, you make `total_time` equal to the start time plus one day, but don't keep track of that change for subsequent days.

Here is a slightly cleaned-up version of your code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

with open("C:\Users\curnutte\Desktop\Assignment\Python Scripts\Python example\RandomFile.txt", "r") as inp:
with open("C:\Users\curnutte\Desktop\Assignment\Python Scripts\Python example\RandomFileOutput.txt", "w") as outp:
    clock = datetime.now()

    for line in inp.readlines():
        total = 0
        line = line.strip().split(",")
        for part in parts:
            try:
                total += int(part)    
            except ValueError:
                total = " ".join(parts)
                break

        if type(total) == int:
            clock += timedelta(minutes = 1)
        else:
            clock += timedelta(days = 1)

        outp.write("{} {}\n".format(clock, total))
```

Notice that I'm now using `clock` in a different way -- I'm constantly replacing it with an updated `datetime` object so it keeps track of the change in time with each iteration of the loop.

This isn't the only way to do what you want, by any means, but the core idea is that you need to keep track of the changing time in some fashion.

Comment: The code you provided did give me errors when I ran it. However, I used the new clock format in the way you suggested and that gave me the results I wanted! I have been working on this for a few days and find it bewildering that such a simple change would be the fix. Thank you for your input!

Comment: @NewAtThis: oh, whoops, sorry about that -- I didn't really thoroughly test my code. I hope it didn't take too much effort to debug it!

Comment: Not at all! Significantly less than what I would have been doing without your assistance